# how to calculate the number of items per page and their index using javascript?

Tags: javascript, pagination

I am building a pagination system for a table and want to show a text like `1 to 5 of 14 entries` i have the following code

```js
var totalItemsCount = 14;
var numberOfItemsPerPage = 5;
var page = 1;

var numberOfPages = Math.floor((totalItemsCount + numberOfItemsPerPage - 1) / numberOfItemsPerPage);

var start = (page * numberOfItemsPerPage) - (numberOfItemsPerPage - 1);

var end = start + numberOfItemsPerPage - 1;

console.log(`${start} to ${end} of ${totalItemsCount}`);
```

now this works well when the number of items per page can equally divide the total number of items but when that is not the case `end` will be incorrect. in the following case if the variable `page` is 3 `end` will be of by `1`. **how can i fix this?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Math.min` to make sure that `end` does not exceed the total number of items.
Here is another solution which looks simpler for me:

```js
function getPaginationText(totalItemsCount, numberOfItemsPerPage, page) {
  var pagesCount = (totalItemsCount - 1) / numberOfItemsPerPage + 1;
  var start = (page - 1) * numberOfItemsPerPage + 1;
  var end = Math.min(start + numberOfItemsPerPage - 1, totalItemsCount);

  return `${start} to ${end} of ${totalItemsCount}`;
}

console.log(getPaginationText(14, 5, 1));
console.log(getPaginationText(14, 5, 2));
console.log(getPaginationText(14, 5, 3));
```

As you can see, you don't need `Math.floor`, you can utilize integer division.

Answer (score 15):

You could use [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min).

```
var end = Math.min(start + numberOfItemsPerPage - 1, totalItemsCount);
```

e.g.

```js
var totalItemsCount = 14;
var numberOfItemsPerPage = 5;
var page = 3;

var numberOfPages = Math.floor((totalItemsCount + numberOfItemsPerPage - 1) / numberOfItemsPerPage);
var start = (page * numberOfItemsPerPage) - (numberOfItemsPerPage - 1);
var end = Math.min(start + numberOfItemsPerPage - 1, totalItemsCount);

console.log(`${start} to ${end} of ${totalItemsCount}`);
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use a slightly different approach for calculating the parameter.

```js
var pagination = (page, total, itemsOnPage) => {
        var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(total / itemsOnPage),
            start = (page - 1) * itemsOnPage + 1,
            end = Math.min(page * itemsOnPage, total);

        return `${start} to ${end} of ${total} on page ${page} of ${numberOfPages}`;
    };
   
console.log(pagination(1, 14, 5));
console.log(pagination(2, 14, 5));
console.log(pagination(3, 14, 5));
console.log(pagination(3, 15, 5));
```